# wxpython - Menu interaction

Tags: menu, wxpython

I'm having trouble with a menu system - I have a basic example here (below) that shows a basic menu example I've followed; specifically, my issue is how may I make decisions from use menu choices, I'm not sure how to interact user choice with a menu choice?
Could someone point me in the right direction, or ideally give a brief example on this - say input data from a menu and display this?

Thanks

```
import wx

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id,'Menu', size=(300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        status     = self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar    = wx.MenuBar()
        firstMenu  = wx.Menu() 
        secondMenu = wx.Menu()


        # create files
        firstMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), 'Save Data'  , 'Save data')        
        firstMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), 'Open Data..', 'Open a new window') 
        secondMenu.Append(wx.NewId(),'Configure..', 'Input Data here')
        # append to menu
        menubar.Append(firstMenu, 'File')
        menubar.Append(secondMenu,'Options')
        # 
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

if( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = myFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind `wx.EVT_MENU` event. See wxPython demo for more examples. In your case that would be somethink like:

```
import wx

SAVE_DATA = wx.NewId()
OPEN_DATA = wx.NewId()
CONFIGURE = wx.NewId()

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id,'Menu', size=(300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        status     = self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar    = wx.MenuBar()
        firstMenu  = wx.Menu() 
        secondMenu = wx.Menu()

        # create files
        firstMenu.Append(SAVE_DATA, 'Save Data'  , 'Save data')        
        firstMenu.Append(OPEN_DATA, 'Open Data..', 'Open a new window') 
        secondMenu.Append(CONFIGURE,'Configure..', 'Input Data here')
        # append to menu
        menubar.Append(firstMenu, 'File')
        menubar.Append(secondMenu,'Options')
        # 
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.SaveData, id=SAVE_DATA)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OpenData, id=OPEN_DATA)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Configure, id=CONFIGURE)

    def SaveData(self, e):
        print("Save")

    def OpenData(self, e):
        print("Open")

    def Configure(self, e):
        print("Config")

if( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = myFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Jake, you should start accepting helpful answers. It is done by clicking check-mark symbol under the upvote / downvote.